# AVAudioRecorder: Why can't I record audio using two UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, avaudioplayer, audio-recording

It keeps saying:

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

I assume the problem is the second view controller is failing to unwrap the recorded audio from the first view controller.

1ST VIEWCONTROLER RECORD SOUND

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class RecordSoundsViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var recordingInProgress: UILabel!

    var audioRecorder : AVAudioRecorder!

    var recordedAudio : RecordedAudio!


    @IBOutlet weak var recordButt: UIButton!



    @IBAction func stopRecording(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("stopTheButton", sender: recordedAudio )
        print("recording is succesful")
        recordingInProgress.hidden = true
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try! audioSession.setActive(false)
        stopButton.hidden = true
        recordButt.enabled = true


    }


    @IBOutlet var stopButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        stopButton.hidden = true
        recordingInProgress.hidden = true
        recordButt.enabled = true
    }


    @IBAction func recordingButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        recordingInProgress.hidden=false;
        recordButt.enabled = false

        stopButton.hidden = false
        print("recording");

        let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String

        let recordingName = "my_audio.wav"
        let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
        let filePath = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathArray)
        print(filePath)

        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)

        try! audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: filePath!, settings: [:])
        // added code--

         audioRecorder.delegate = self

        // added above code
        audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
        audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
        audioRecorder.record()

           }
    func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
        //todo: save the recorded audio

        if flag {
        recordedAudio = RecordedAudio()
        recordedAudio.filePathUrl = recorder.url
        recordedAudio.title = recorder.url.lastPathComponent
            // pass the file over to the next view where we can apply audio effects


            if recordButt.enabled == true {

                audioRecorder.stop()
            } else {

                print("not enabled")

            }

        } else {
            print("recording was mot succesful")
            stopButton.hidden = true
            recordButt.enabled = true


        }

        func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

            if (segue.identifier == "stopTheButton") {

            let playSoundsVC : soundPlayViewController = segue.destinationViewController as!soundPlayViewController
                let data = sender as! RecordedAudio
                playSoundsVC.receivedAudio = data


            } else {

                print("recording not successful")
            }
        }

        // to move to the next scene---




    }


}
```

SECOND VIEWCONTROLER: SOUND PLAY

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class soundPlayViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!

    var receivedAudio:RecordedAudio!

    @IBOutlet var stopButton1:UIButton!


    func configureViewToPlay() {

        audioPlayer.stop()
        audioPlayer.play()
        audioPlayer.currentTime = 0
        stopButton1.hidden = false

    }

    @IBAction func playSlow(sender: UIButton) {

        configureViewToPlay()
        audioPlayer.rate = 0.5



    }

    @IBAction func playFast(sender: UIButton) {

        configureViewToPlay()
        audioPlayer.rate = 1.9

    }

    @IBAction func stopButton1(sender: UIButton) {

        audioPlayer.stop()
        audioPlayer.currentTime = 0

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()




        //code taken from inside the if statement to disable movie quote and enable recording...

        if stopButton1.hidden == true {

        audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: receivedAudio.filePathUrl, fileTypeHint:"wav")
        audioPlayer.enableRate = true
        audioPlayer.stop()
        audioPlayer.rate = 2.0
        audioPlayer.currentTime = 0.0
        audioPlayer.play()
        }


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        stopButton1.hidden = true

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }                    
}
```

Comment: Please include a copy of the log with that error.

Comment: We need to see full error description

Comment: The error says: recording
Optional(file:///Users/frazynondo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0A1C9B83-758C-4744-8F9E-4F47C57246F2/data/Containers/Data/Application/73FC8B84-213D-4BEA-9328-56AC41BF86E2/Documents/my_audio.wav)
recording is succesful
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: Is that enough information? Let me know

Comment: cid:7260E0F0-E05C-4876-9BE0-AEEBB13A3E80